# Python word length function example needed

Tags: python, string

I'm having a little bit of trouble with my homework.  I was supposed to write a function "limitWords" that restricts input to twenty words and truncates the input down to only 20 words if it's more than 20 words.

I used "len(text.split())" as a means to count up the words, so the 20 or less part works, but I don't know how to truncate the input without changing it into a twenty word list.

I don't know if the way I did the first part of my if statement properly, but input on the second bit would be helpful.  I'm not looking for a copy and paste answer -- explanation or an example that's similar would be preferred.  Thanks!

```
totalwords = len(text.split())
if totalwords <= 20:
    return text
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the list approach is quite viable -- you're almost there already.

Your `text.split()` already produces an array of words, so you can do:

```
words = text.split()
totalwords = len(words)
```

Then, you could select the first 20 as you say (if there's too many words), and join the array back together.

To join, look at [str.join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

As an example:

```
'||'.join(['eggs','and','ham'])
# returns 'eggs||and||ham'
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem in using lists here. You can do something like

```
>>> st = "abc def ghi"
>>> words = st.split()
>>> words
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
>>> if len(words)>2:
...     print " ".join(words[:2])
...
abc def
```

In the above case the word limit is `2` and I used [List Slicing](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html) and `str.join()` to get the required output.

Comment: Thanks to you too.  Very helpful example!

Answer (score 1):

Presuming the `split()` works as you intend, why not recombine the first 20 items into a string and return it?

Comment: Thank you, too!  Really helpful - I've got it now!