# Count number of words per row

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new column in a DataFrame that contains the word count for the respective row.  I'm looking for the total number of words, not frequencies of each distinct word. I assumed there would be a simple/quick way to do this common task, but after googling around and reading a handful of SO posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970203/how-to-count-average-sentence-length-in-words-from-a-text-file-contains-100-se), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108377/how-to-use-the-split-function-on-every-row-in-a-dataframe-in-python), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288169/python-word-length-function-example-needed), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677020/real-word-count-in-nltk#10677060)) I'm stuck. I've tried the solutions put forward in the linked SO posts, but got lots of attribute errors back.

```
words = df['col'].split()
df['totalwords'] = len(words)
```

results in

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

and

```
f = lambda x: len(x["col"].split()) -1
df['totalwords'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

results in

```
AttributeError: ("'list' object has no attribute 'split'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

#### `str.split` + `str.len`

`str.len` works nicely for any non-numeric column.

```
df['totalwords'] = df['col'].str.split().str.len()
```

---

#### `str.count`

If your words are single-space separated, you may simply count the spaces plus 1.

```
df['totalwords'] = df['col'].str.count(' ') + 1
```

---

#### List Comprehension

This is faster than you think!

```
df['totalwords'] = [len(x.split()) for x in df['col'].tolist()]
```

Comment: @lucid_dreamer it splits each string on whitespace into a list of words, then returns the length of each list.

Comment: but why not just `df['totalwords'] = df['col'].str.split().len()`?

Comment: @lucid_dreamer because that's not correct? There's no len() function defined on Series.

Comment: I'm confused. First str.split() -> returns a series where each element is a lists right? After that I'm lost.

Comment: oh! I get it now: str.len can operate on arbitrary lists, it's not a string-specific function. Confusing.

Comment: @lucid_dreamer Take a look at [Working with Text Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html), pandas has a suite of str methods defined on object dtype columns, some of them (such as `str.len()` and `str.count()`) work for arbitrary containers.

Comment: If you have things like commas, this will count them as words. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444346/fast-punctuation-removal-with-pandas) for how to remove the punctuation before getting the word count.

Comment: List comprehension is much faster. It took me 1 min, vs 3 min of the split+len method

Answer (score 17):

Here is a way using `.apply()`:

```
df['number_of_words'] = df.col.apply(lambda x: len(x.split()))
```

**example**

Given this `df`:

```
>>> df
                    col
0  This is one sentence
1           and another
```

After applying the `.apply()`

```
df['number_of_words'] = df.col.apply(lambda x: len(x.split()))

>>> df
                    col  number_of_words
0  This is one sentence                4
1           and another                2
```

**Note**: As pointed out by in comments, and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38708239/6671176), `.apply` is not necessarily the fastest method. If speed is important, better go with one of [@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49984997/6671176) methods.

Comment: apply = slower version of a loop. This is a good idea, but something like `[len(x.split()) for x in df['col']]` would be prime. It's in my answer but feel free to add it to yours as well.

Answer (score 8):

This is one way using [`pd.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['word_count'] = df['col'].str.split().map(len)
```

The above assumes that `df['col']` is a series of strings.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['This is an example', 'This is another', 'A third']})

df['word_count'] = df['col'].str.split().map(len)

print(df)

#                   col  word_count
# 0  This is an example           4
# 1     This is another           3
# 2             A third           2
```

Answer (score 4):

With `list` and `map` data from cold

```
list(map(lambda x : len(x.split()),df.col))
Out[343]: [4, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also `map` `split` and `len` methods to the strings in the DataFrame column:

```
df['word_count'] = [*map(len, map(str.split, df['col'].tolist()))]
```

Here's some preliminary benchmark of the answers given here. `map` seems to do well on very large Series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['one apple','banana','box of oranges','pile of fruits outside', 
                   'one banana', 'fruits']*100000, 
                  columns=['col'])
>>> df.shape
(600000, 1)

>>> %timeit df['word_count'] = df['col'].str.split().str.len()
761 ms ± 43.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit df['word_count'] = df['col'].str.count(' ').add(1)
691 ms ± 71.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit df['word_count'] = [len(x.split()) for x in df['col'].tolist()]
405 ms ± 13.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit df['word_count'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split()))
450 ms ± 22.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit df['word_count'] = df['col'].str.split().map(len)
657 ms ± 27.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit df['word_count'] = list(map(lambda x : len(x.split()), df['col'].tolist()))
435 ms ± 21.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit df['word_count'] = [*map(len, map(str.split, df['col'].tolist()))]
329 ms ± 20.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a simple regex expression within Pandas' built-in str.count() method:

```
df['total_words'] = df['col'].str.count('\w+')
```

- `\w` character class matches any word character, which includes any letter, digit, or underscore. It is equivalent to the character range [A-Za-z0-9_].
- `+` sign for 1 or unlimited repeat times.

Or use the following regex if you would like words consisting of alphabetic symbols only:

```
  df['total_words'] = df['col'].str.count('[A-Za-z]+')
```