# How to do word count on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I know this is may be silly, but every research I've done for this question is led to more complex questions, I still can't figure out the basics, I just want to count the frequency of words

Here's my data

```
id descriptions
1  I love you
2  I love you too
```

Here's my expected output

```
id descriptions      word count
1  I love you        3
2  I love you too    4
```

Comment: Identical duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49984905/count-number-of-words-per-row/49984997#49984997 and likely many others.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use:

```
df['count'] = df['descriptions'].str.count(' ') + 1
```

Or:

```
df['count'] = df['descriptions'].str.split().str.len()
```

Or:

```
df['count'] = df['descriptions'].str.findall(r'(\w+)').str.len()
```

---

```
print (df)
   id    descriptions  count
0   1      I love you      3
1   2  I love you too      4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
df['word_count'] = df['description'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split())
```