# Count words in two different columns and sum them by row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to count the number of words in two different columns and safe the result of the addition in an extra column.

Example of the data and desired result:

```
id  question                     answer             word_count
1   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor  8
2   Lorem ipsum                  ipsum              3
3   Lorem ipsum dolor sit        Lorem              5
```

Following code is not working:

```
df['word_count'] = df[['question', 'answer']].apply(lambda x: len(str(x).split(" ")))
```

Comment: Sum individual columns using [Count number of words per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49984905/count-number-of-words-per-row?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str.len` with `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
df["word_count"] = df['question'].str.split().str.len() + df['answer'].str.split().str.len()
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                     question             answer  word_count
0  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  Lorem ipsum dolor           8
1                 Lorem ipsum              ipsum           3
2       Lorem ipsum dolor sit              Lorem           5
```

Comment: i prefer this answer because it is not using .apply()

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['word_count'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: len(row['question'].strip().split()) + 
                len(row['answer'].strip().split()), axis=1)
```

In short, how it works. `df.apply(func, axis=1)` applies the function `func` for each row in the data frame and generates a series of results. `.strip()` is needed to cut leading and trailing spaces if they are. `.split()` makes a list of separate words of the string. `len()` calculates the number of elements of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['word_count'] = df['question'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x).split(" ")))+df['answer'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x).split(" ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Split and Add two columns and then apply `len`:

```
(df['Question'].str.split(" ")+df['Answer'].str.split(" ")).apply(len)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can count the empty strings with `str.count` and sum:

```
df['word_count'] = (df[['question','answer']]
    .apply(lambda x: x.str.count('\s+')+1).sum(1)
)
```

Or we can count the word-characters `\w`:

```
df['word_count'] = (df[['question','answer']]
    .apply(lambda x: x.str.count('\w+')).sum(1)
)
```

Output:

```
   id                    question             answer  word_count
0   1  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  Lorem ipsum dolor           8
1   2                 Lorem ipsum              ipsum           3
2   3       Lorem ipsum dolor sit              Lorem           5
```