# How do I count the words in every row of a data frame column?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to count the number of words in every row of a dataframe column. Every word is separated by a comma. The name of the column is `Items`.

I tried achieving this by looping over every word of the dataframe row using `apply` and `lambda`. However, I am not sure how to count the number of words -

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd

# initialize list elements
data = {'Company': ['Nike', 'Levi', 'Dell'],
        'Items': ['Shoes, Shorts, Socks', 'Jeans, Jackets', 'Laptops']}

# Create the pandas DataFrame with column name is provided explicitly
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['ind_words'] = df.Items.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split(",")]))
df['lengths']  = df['ind_words'].count()

# print dataframe.
print(df.head())
```

Doing this resulted in -

```
  Company                 Items             ind_words  lengths
0    Nike  Shoes, Shorts, Socks  Shoes  Shorts  Socks        3
1    Levi        Jeans, Jackets        Jeans  Jackets        3
2    Dell               Laptops               Laptops        3
```

The column `lengths` is wrong. I understand why the function `count()` is wrong here, but I don't know what function to use.

Here is the ideal output -

```
  Company                 Items  length
0    Nike  Shoes, Shorts, Socks       3
1    Levi        Jeans, Jackets       2
2    Dell               Laptops       1
```

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of `df["Items"].str.split(",").str.len()`?

Comment: You could also count the number of commas! `df["Items"].str.count(",") + 1` ;)

Comment: Duplicate: [Count number of words per row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49984905/4518341)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply(len)`:

```py
df['ind_words'] = df['Items'].str.split(',')
df['lengths']  = df['ind_words'].apply(len)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df["col"].apply(str.split).apply(len)
```

Comment: There's no need to use `.apply` here since the Series has `.str.split` and `.str.len`.

Comment: FYI, OP clarified that the words are comma-separated, not whitespace-separated.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting is expensive, count the delimiters and add 1 (eventually checking if not null):

```
df['length'] = df['Items'].str.count(',').add(1)
```

Or, if you can have empty/blank strings:

```
df['length'] = df['Items'].str.count(',').add(~df['Items'].str.fullmatch(r'\s*'))
```